# How to auto delete and sort excel cells if it matches among other cells in a row

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

[image]

This sheet has 6 columns of which B column is answer of Column A 
It is a multiple choice question which has four option in c, d, e, f column

I want B column to be untouched> Search in B1 and delete any found result from C1 D1 E1 and F1> then sort so that only c1 d1 and e1 exists and f1 is deleted

Like,

Correct answer to the question of A1 is in both B1 and c1 . I want C1 to be deleted and sort the rest of the cells in the row 1 so that d1 (a poet of love) moves to c1, e1 moves to d1 and f1 moves to e1

Similarly,

Correct answer to the question of a2 is in both b2 cell and e2 cell

I want data of e2 to be deleted and data of f2 move to e2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you.

```
   Sub TableExample()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim address As String
    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Dim r As Range: Set r = .Range("A1", "A" & lastrow)
    End With
    For Each cell In r.Cells
        For i = 1 To 4
            If cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Offset(0, 1 + i).Value Then
                address = cell.Offset(0, 1 + i).address(0, 0)
                Exit For
            Else
                address = "0"
            End If
        Next
        If address <> "0" Then
            Dim rr As Range: Set rr = ActiveSheet.Range(address)
            For i = 1 To 4
                rr.Value = rr.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Set rr = rr.Offset(0, 1)
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh I see the problem was in "SheetName = "Sheet1" Since My doc do not have a sheet named "Sheet1"

I changed the name to "ETC" and it worked!

Comment: Change the sheetname accordingly. Tell me if it works!

Comment: I am new to excel VBA and was curious to see if there is a way to automate this even further. Like I have a few couple of Sheet in my doc. All are similar kind of data and needs to implement. 

since it is mandatory to change the Sheet name each time I want to implement this on my doc. Can you manage to bypass this name changing? like when I am on the sheet called "poets" and go for run the macro it automatically selects that sheet? I am just curious!

Comment: It should do what you want on the activated sheet. Vote up if it works :)

Comment: Yes it worked except this edition has a minor error you forgot to add "End Sub" 

Super Job!!!!

Comment: I would have voted but I need more reputation since I am new here and someone has already lowerd my reputation by voted to this question negatively. I appreciate your help and I will come back and vote up your answer when I have enough reputation score. Thanks

Comment: No problem @Dinaji. Happy you got your answer :)